# WebHdfs could not reslove hostname while GET operation

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I am trying to fetch a file using `WebHdfs` by Postman my `GET` request is:

`http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/hduser/json/json_record.json?op=OPEN`

I am getting a `dns_unresolved_hostname` error. On the other hand if I do `op=LISTSTATUS` I am getting the correct result.

Is there something wrong in the request :
`http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/hduser/json/json_record.json?op=OPEN`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to download/open file using WebHdfs, but op=OPEN argument is giving dns_resolved error

Comment: Where does the error come from? A `LISTSTATUS` doesn't reach a datanode, so the namenode is clearly working fine, but anything else would be reaching out to a datanode server, and the DNS resolution there might not work

Comment: The documentation says when we try to open a file it will redirect to data node. So I guess the redirection is automatic right ? And if its failing during redirection how I can resolve it ?